# Finding Counts Of Points In Each Census Block using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Hi so I am trying to find counts of points in each census blocks using STIntersects. The process is slow and I am just making sure I am doing this right with my query below. If anyone has a better suggestion on how I can go about it or improve this process please comment below.

So I am trying to understand NYC taxi demand using census blocks. I am using STintersects with taxi drop off points and Census blocks of New york. How should I go about getting the counts per block to make a density map.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT p.ID,p.TYPE,b.pop10,b.blockid10,
    COUNT (p.GEOM) AS NumberOfPoints 
FROM 
    [dbo].[BLOCK_NYC] as b,
    [dbo].[PUGeom_Oct]as p
WHERE 
    p.geom.STIntersects(b.GEOM) = 1
GROUP BY 
     p.ID,p.TYPE,b.pop10,b.blockid10
```

I was also thinking of doing like this:

```
SELECT blockid10,COUNT (p.GEOM) AS NumberOfPoints FROM 
[dbo].[BLOCK_NYC] as b,[dbo].[PUGeom_Oct] as p
WHERE p.Geom.STContains(p.geom) = 1
GROUP BY blockid10
```

How should I go about it?

Comment: What is STIntersects?

Comment: @JonH https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb933899.aspx

Comment: @JonH https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933899.aspx. It is like a spatial join.

Comment: okay thanks, never heard of it so I can't help...but as long as you know what COUNT and GROUP BY do there isn't much else you can do.

Comment: Do you have any spatial indexes?

Comment: @MartinSmith I was thinking of using that. I am kinda new to spatial data and big data. Can you suggest of how we can go about that.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think a spatial index will help but I am just wondering if my query is right. :)